# adding parameter between URL in django

Tags: python, django, django-urls

I am a beginner in Django. I want to pass a parameter to a URL. Here is how I want the URL to look like:

```
/category/<parameter>/add_page/
```

What is the regular expression for this url?

Comment: You just accepted an answer that won't work--in any version of django with any version of python.

Comment: @7stud it worked on django 1.7 and python 2.7

Comment: No.  When you accepted the answer--it had errors in it.  After I posted my answer, catavaran changed his answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will catch all non-slash chars:

```
url(r'^category/(?P<parameter>[^/]+)/add_page/$', views.my_view),
```

If you want to limit characters to alphanumeric and dash `-` (for example for slug) then use this regex:

```
url(r'^category/(?P<parameter>[\w-]+)/add_page/$', views.my_view),
```

For digits only use:

```
url(r'^category/(?P<parameter>\d+)/add_page/$', views.my_view),
```

Answer (score 0):

catavaran's answer has errors.  Try this:

```
r'^category/(?P<cool_stuff>\w+)/add_page/$'
```

The key part is here:

```
/(?P<cool_stuff>\w+)/
```

...

```
<cool_stuff>  => the name by which you want to refer to the value  
\w+           => a 'word' character, 1 or more times => [a-zA-Z0-9_]+
\d+           => a digit, 1 or more times  
[^/]+         => not a slash, i.e. any character, one or more times
```

You can choose which of those you want to put in place of `\w+`.